# Android - Deprecated NDK warnings in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

After a long time working fine my project suddenly build failed. The image below is what i get from log.

[image]

I already have gradle.properties file with 'android.useDeprecatedNdk=true' in my project but the error keep show up.

Please help. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning says that `useDeprecatedNdk=true` will stop working soon. If you plan to keep using the latest Gradle Plugin, you should edit your **build.gradle** and use **externalNativeBuild**.

Actually, the change should be pretty easy, and the explanation on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#ndkCompile) is quite straightforward.

The error you see is probably not related to the warning. Something went wrong in your build. The easiest way to find out is to run same **ndk-build** in the terminal window of your Android Studio, and analyze the results.

Carefully copy all parameters from the log, and add `V=1`:

```
/Users/haulx94/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/haulx94/AndroidProject/hd1-android/HDONE/app/build/intermediates/ndk/stagging/debug/Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-25 NDK_OUT=/Users/haulx94/AndroidProject/hd1-android/HDONE/app/build/intermediates/ndk/stagging/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/haulx94/AndroidProject/hd1-android/HDONE/app/build/intermediates/ndk/stagging/debug/lib APP_STL=gnustl_shared APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a V=1
```